# Retrieve single quoted string from database

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I've a field 'NAME' in my oracle 11g  database. The NAME is a field which contains single quoted string. E.g King's Company. 
When i try to retrieve these kind of strings the error is generated "Query string not properly handled". This is may be because of single quote ('). Please help me to ignore these characters, and display string in asp.net application.

Comment: Show us input and output, prepare a script (`CREATE TABLE T ...; INSERT INTO T ...`) or just a simple query with the section `WITH` (`WITH t AS (SELECT ...) SELECT * FROM t...`)

Comment: Try to use `\` before your `quote` to tell db that your is included in that field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a temp table and populated it with sample data:
[image]

This will be the query:

```
select emp_id from temp where name='King''s Company';
```

The reason behind this is:
As `'` (single quote) already has a special meaning in oracle and also it cannot be escapped by using the normal escape character like `%\_%` or `%\%%` etc. For the `'` (single quote) if you want to escape any single quote in your query, just add another single quote before it.

HOPE THIS HELPS...